# Difference between min_samples_split and min_samples_leaf in sklearn DecisionTreeClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I was going through sklearn class [DecisionTreeClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html).

Looking at parameters for the class, we have two parameters **min_samples_split** and **min_samples_leaf**. Basic idea behind them looks similar, you specify a minimum number of samples required to decide a node to be leaf or split further.

Why do we need two parameters when one implies the other?. Is there any reason or scenario which distinguish them?.

Comment: https://discuss.analyticsvidhya.com/t/what-does-min-samples-split-means-in-decision-tree/6233/2

Comment: @Abhishek, thanks for the link. Both Alex and the link helped me understand it now.

Comment: There's another big discussion of it here including diagrams https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8399

Answer (score 88, accepted):

From the documentation:

> The main difference between the two is that `min_samples_leaf` guarantees a minimum number of samples in a leaf, while `min_samples_split` can create arbitrary small leaves, though `min_samples_split` is more common in the literature.

To get a grasp of this piece of documentation I think you should make the distinction between a **leaf** (also called **external node**) and an **internal node**. An internal node will have further splits (also called **children**), while a leaf is by definition a node without any children (without any further splits).

`min_samples_split` specifies the minimum number of samples required to split an *internal node*, while `min_samples_leaf` specifies the minimum number of samples required to be at a *leaf* node.

For instance, if `min_samples_split = 5`, and there are 7 samples at an internal node, then the split is allowed. But let's say the split results in two leaves, one with 1 sample, and another with 6 samples. If `min_samples_leaf = 2`, then the split won't be allowed (even if the internal node has 7 samples) because one of the leaves resulted will have less then the minimum number of samples required to be at a leaf node.

As the documentation referenced above mentions, `min_samples_leaf` guarantees a minimum number of samples in every leaf, no matter the value of `min_samples_split`.

Comment: Thanks @Alex. I get it now. min_samples_split does not guarantee min samples in leaf node but min_samples_leaf would.

Comment: But in the case of a binary classification with a RandomForestClassifier, if the leaf node has more than 1  sample (datapoint), let say two, how is the decision taken, which class they belong to? class 0 or class 1? They are 2, we cannot say if class 1 or class 2. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @ZelelB By definition if the samples end up in the leaf node then they are being classified as having the same class.

Comment: What would be a motivation for having min_samples_leaf == 2?

Answer (score 11):

Both parameters will produce similar results, the difference is the point of view.

The **min_samples_split** parameter will evaluate the number of samples in the node, and if the number is less than the minimum the split will be avoided and the node will be a leaf.

The **min_samples_leaf** parameter checks before the node is generated, that is, if the possible split results in a child with fewer samples, the split will be avoided (since the minimum number of samples for the child to be a leaf has not been reached) and the node will be replaced by a leaf.

In all cases, when we have samples with more than one Class in a leaf, the Final Class will be the most likely to happen, according to the samples that reached it in training.

Answer (score 7):

lets say that **min_samples_split = 9**  and **min_samples_leaf =3** .

in the internal node,right split not allowed (3<9) and  left split is allowed (10>9) .
but because min_samples_leaf =3  and  one leaf is 2 (the right one)  so 10 **will not split** to 2 and 8.

Look at the leaf with the number 3 (from the first splitting).
If we decide that  mim_samples_leaf =4 and not 3 so even the first splitting would not be happen (13 to 10 and 3) .

[image]

Comment: Your representation is wrong. You says min_samples_leaf equals 5, therefore min_samples_leaf should not be less than 5. Leaves that has 2 and 3 samples break the rule.

Comment: you right.  look at the end of my explanation.  I said   "it will not split".

Answer (score 6):

In decision trees, there are many rules one can set up to configure how the tree should end up. Roughly, there are more 'design' oriented rules like  max_depth. Max_depth is more like when you build a house, the architect asks you how many floors you want on the house.

Some other rules are 'defensive' rules. We often call them stopping rules. min_samples_leaf and min_samples_split belong to this type. All explanations already provided are very well said. My cent: rules interact when the tree is being built. For example, min_samples_leaf=100, you may very well end up with tree where all the terminal nodes are way larger than 100 because others rule kick in to have stopped the tree from expanding.

Answer (score 2):

min_sample_split  tells above the minimum no. of samples reqd. to split an internal node. If an integer value is taken then consider min_samples_split as the minimum no. If float, then it shows the percentage. By default, it takes “2” value.

min_sample_leaf is the minimum number of samples required to be at a leaf node. If an integer value is taken then consider - -min_samples_leaf as the minimum no. If float, then it shows the percentage. By default, it takes “1” value.